# Rewriting book in Bachelor Thesis

Tags: writing, bachelor, copy-editing

Is it okay to just rewrite whole chapters from a book while describing a theory you are using in your Bachelor Thesis? Is it okay to only have two books as references and few (3-5) papers on arxiv to cite?

Comment: In math there is the concept of "In the following chapter we follow the developments from [Archimedes]." Use it if you need the prerequisites later. Of course, this should not be your main contribution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to beware of copyright law here. A "rewriting" of a chapter could be construed as a derived work, for which a license is needed. It is better to formally quote small excerpts as needed. Even paraphrasing, if excessive, can involve copyright issues. And of course, you need to cite what you use to avoid plagiarism.

The number of books/papers that you need to cite is best asked of your advisor(s) and what they will accept. It is a purely local question.

Note, however, that some things fall under the "common knowledge" exception to IP conventions. You can write your own understanding of things you've learned if they are common knowledge. Most undergraduate material (certainly not all) fits this exception.

But, for practice in learning to be an academic, if that is your goal, a rather formal approach (quoting, citing) is probably in your interest. The reader is pointed to the originals and can consult that as necessary.

Comment: Would the part about licensing still apply if the work is submitted to the university but not published/distributed?

Comment: Better to assume that it does. It is a form of "publishing", even if limited. Some libraries might make theses available, for example.

Answer (score 2):

Don't quote or paraphrase whole chapters: extract and rework the material you actually need.

Whatever sources you use, be sure to cite them properly.

Whether those chapters and the several arXiv references are "enough" depends on the subject matter, the kind of dissertation, and the standards in your program. Talk to advisors in your department and look at other theses submitted at  your school to get an idea of what is expected.